# Equivalente de "discoverability" en español

Tags: verbos, sustantivos

Estoy estudiando redes de computadoras y en el libro Head First Networking aparece un término que sí entiendo pero quisiera saber si existe algún equivalente en español para él, el término es "discoverability", se podría traducir como 'descubribilidad' o 'encontrabilidad', pero estas no están en el diccionario de la RAE.

Poniendome a pensar me di cuenta que tal vez en el español pueda haber alguna regla que permita convertir verbos en sustantivos aunque no esten en el diccionario ni se usen cotidianamente.

Answer (score 6):

Si buscas un término apropiado acorde a las definiciones de la RAE, lo mas cercano sería detectable.

> **detectable**
>
> 1. adj. Que se puede detectar.
>
> **detectar**
>
> (Del ingl. to detect).
>
> 1. tr. Descubrir la existencia de algo que no era patente.

Ahora bien, derivando de estos términos podríamos traducir `discoverability` como **`detectabilidad`** aunque dicho término tampoco se encuentra en la RAE.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque Google no lo encuentra, intentaría:

> "*descubrible*" -> "*descubribilidad*" ...

Comment: Mala derivación. Sería 'descubribilidad' como dice la pregunta inicial.

Comment: @Envite claro, me di cuenta del barbarismo.